# PHP Date - How to add a string to separate date and time

Tags: php, date, date-formatting

I want to display date and time format something like this `"May 23 at 12:30pm"`.
I saw in PHP manual and found:

```
// Prints something like: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

After modification I manage to get

```
 echo date('M j \of h:i a');
```

it is giving me `"May 23 of 12:30pm"`

but when i replacing `of` with `at` it is giving me `"May 23 a23 08:26 pm"`.

I don't what is going wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you need to escape the `a` and `t` as both have special meaning when used as formatting options in `date()`

```
echo date('M j \a\t h:i a');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yPdHRH)

Comment: Make sure not to use double quotes in date string, it could produce unexpected result.

Comment: \t didnt work for me rather `echo date('M j'). "at". date(' h:i a');` worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
<?php
    echo date('M j \a\t h:i a');
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
    echo date('M j'). "at". date(' h:i a');
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the `t` too:

```
echo date('M j \a\t h:i a');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this in php:

```
$t = now(); //This will give you current time
echo date_format($t,"dS M,y \a\\t h:i a"); //14th May,19 at 05:39am
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be:

```
echo date('M j')." at ".date('h:i a');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, if want to add "at" between date and time

```
date("d/m/Y \a\\t h:i A", strtotime($date_created)); // for string
date("d/m/Y \a\\t h:i A", $date_created); // for UNIX time
```